# missing /opt for firefox esr install

Tags: firefox

wanted to install firefox esr via the package from mozilla.com and still want to. Found an guide to do so which includes to unpack the package to /opt = "sudo tar -xvjf firefox-10.0.2.tar.bz2 -C /opt". Well surprise there is no /opt in elementary loki and i really don't want to use any PPA.

**My Question(s)**:

- does it matter where to extract the package? means do i need to create /opt?
- or is there another way? whats my best Option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract it anywhere as long as you don't create a conflict with `firefox` dependencies. To be safe and for ease of finding its location, I recommend just putting it on `/opt`.

Just create the `/opt` directory manually via terminal or file manager with root privileges. Since elementary doesn't use it by default, it's safe to put manually downloaded software in it.

Comment: created /opt with 775 permissions